# Sum of two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, sum

The exercise says "Make a function with parameters two int arrays and k which is their size. The function should return another array (size k) where every element of it is the sum of the two arrays of the same position. That's what I wrote, but it crashes. Do I have to do it with pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sumarray(int k,int A[k],int B[k]){
   int sum[k],i;
   for(i=0;i<k;i++){                
   sum[i]=A[i]+B[i];
   printf("sum[%d]=%d\n",i,sum[i]);}

 }



main(){
   int i,g,a[g],b[g];
   printf("Give size of both arrays: ");
   scanf("%d",&g);
   for(i=0;i<g;i++){
      a[i]=rand();
      b[i]=rand();
   }
   sumarray(g,a,b);
   system("pause");
}
```

Example: If i have A={1,2,3,4} and B={4,3,2,1} the program will return C={5,5,5,5).

Comment: How far does it get before it crashes?

Comment: What is the crash? What is the error message? with what input?

Comment: `a` and `b` should be pointers:`int *a, *b`, then initialize the arrays with `malloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: @Oli @David It doesn't even start. I get a black screen and the I get a error message and the program ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
int i,g,a[g],b[g];
```

causes *undefined* behaviour.  The value of `g` is undefined upon initialisation, so therefore the length of `a` and `b` will be undefined.

You probably want something like:

```
int i, g;
int *a;
int *b;  // Note: recommend declaring on separate lines, to avoid issues
scanf("%d", &g);
a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * g);
b = malloc(sizeof(*b) * g);
...
free(a);
free(b);
```

Comment: so what should i put in? The user will give the size of the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Its impossible to first do `a[g]` when dynamically getting `g`.

Your first lines in main should be:

```
int i,g;
int *a,*b;
printf("Give size of both arrays: ");
scanf("%d",&g);
a = (int *)malloc(g*sizeof(int));
b = (int *)malloc(g*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum[k] ;
```

`k` is a variable but the size of the array should be a constant.

> The function should return another array (size k) ...

But the function you wrote returns `void` which is clearly wrong.

> Do I have to do it with pointers?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you've attempted to declare dynamically sized arrays on the stack (e.g. `a[g]`).  You need to declare pointers for each array and then dynamically allocate your variable sized array once you've read in the value of `g`.

Comment: Should I do something like 'a[l]' and then 'g=&l'? I'm not very good at pointers.

Comment: In C99, it would be ok to declare the variable length arrays after `g` has been read in.  But for general-purpose C, then yes, this is what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

change the function summary signature (the definition part of the declaration) to this and try it out:

`void sumarray(int k,int* A,int* B){`